# Create/Save Users on Rails API using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, rails-api

I have a simple application that serves JSON through the API back end when creating a new user. I'm trying to add AJAX to the request so it doesn't reload the page when a new user is added. I'm really new to AJAX/API and have really no idea what needs to be done.

This is my Users API Controller:

```
class Api::UsersController < Api::BaseController
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

def create
@user = User.create!(user_params)
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to users_list_path, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
  format.json { render json: @index }
  format.js
end
end



private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name)
  end

  def query_params
    params.permit(:name)
  end

  end
```

This is my index view(it should refresh with ajax call):

```
<% content_for :title do %>Users<% end %>
<h3>Here is the user list.  Please click on one to see messages.</h3>
<br/>
<% User.all.each do |user| %>
  <p><%= link_to String(user.id) + '. ' + user.name, messages_list_path(user_id: user.id) %></p>
<% end %>
<br/>
<%= form_tag("/api/users.json", method: "post") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:add_user, "Add User:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag("user[name]") %>
  <%= submit_tag("Add") %>
<% end %>
```

The issue I am having is when I add a new user it takes me straight to http://localhost:3000/api/users.json which displays the JSON data. I need the app to basically stay on the same page where the form is and just simply update with AJAX.

I am really new to the building API's in rails as well as AJAX so any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

add `remote: true` to your `form_tag` to submit an ajax call.
see [DOCS](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag)

`form_tag("/api/users.json", method: "post", remote: true)`

Comment: while this is partly correct, the issue i am having is that it continues to render the json data instead of just simply updating the view. should I have a create.js.erb file?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the form automatically redirects you when submitted. You could put in a jQuery event listener to prevent that and then create the new user with an ajax call after, something like:

```
    $('form').on('submit', submitForm.bind(this, event));

    var submitForm = function (event) () {
        event.preventDefault();
        var user = $('form').serialize();

       $.ajax({
           url: "/api/users",
           method: "POST",
           data: user,
           dataType: "json",
           success: function(data){
           this.handleSuccess(data);
           }.bind(this)
        });
      };
```

Not sure if that's exactly what you're looking for, but hope it helps!

Comment: I am going to try this but maybe i should provide a better explanation. My view is /users/index.html which has a list of all users and a form and add user button it. ideally what i want is when i hit add user, it updates index.html instead of redirecting me to the json data.

Comment: I added "remote: true" and now nothing happens but when i refresh the page it adds the record twice.